# Lightning Data Services vs. Streaming API

Tags: streaming-api, lightning-data-service

I have a lightning component which needs to be refreshed when a record is changed in the database. Can I use lightning Data Services or must I use the Streaming API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Lightning Data Service record will only update on-screen if the record is edited/updated in another Lightning Data Service context.

So, assuming that the database change is not done by the same user, I would suggest using Streaming API, or an on-screen polling mechanism that does calls to APEX.